# Why does the query below always return zero results?

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic, ado

The following query always returns empty count. Does anyone know why?

```
SELECT CTM_Export.[Tracking # Label], Count(CTM_Export.[Tracking # Label]) AS LabelCount
FROM CTM_Export
GROUP BY CTM_Export.[Tracking # Label]
HAVING (((CTM_Export.[Tracking # Label])='TPE RV'))

response.write LabelCount
```

In the CTM_Export table there are three rows with the value "TPE RV". Therefore, LabelCount should not be empty. But for some reason it is always null.

Comment: What happens when you remove the HAVING statement?

Comment: Have you tried using `WHERE CTM_Export.[Tracking # Label]='TPE RV'` instead of HAVING?

Comment: I agree Yuriy. It seems to be the HAVING. I guess you don't need this HEAVING... Replace to WHERE...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go back to the data source and examine those values.  Perhaps this query actually returns no rows:

```sql
SELECT ctm.*
FROM CTM_Export AS ctm
WHERE ctm.[Tracking # Label]='TPE RV'
```

You may find the `[Tracking # Label]` values include unexpected space or other non-visible characters.

---

Seeing one of your comments makes me wonder if something else is going on.  Using your original `GROUP BY` query, add this line to your ASP:

```
Response.Write "LabelCount: " & tlRS.Fields("LabelCount").Value
```

Comment: That displays the total number of rows in the table correctly.

Comment: So then the query was not the problem.  The problem was about how you were attempting to retrieve `LabelCount` from a recordset based on that query.  Correct?

Comment: Yes. And it worked! I was able to add my criteria back in and now it all works fine. So why wouldn't a normal response.write work?

Comment: I'm not sure what was going on originally.  But it looks like you were attempting to do something like: `Response.Write <%= LabelCount %>`  However, there was no variable named `LabelCount`, so you got the standard value for an undeclared variant which has not had a value assigned to it ... and that is Null.

Answer (score 0):

Is there an object you are executing the query on? Looks like lots of code is missing here.

You should perform the count on another field, such as the rowID.

I also recommend you also change "HAVING" to "WHERE".

Comment: Changing HAVING to WHERE yields the same results - LabelCount is still empty. This is a raw export from another system so it doesn't have an ID column. Any suggestions? I believe all columns are Short Text.

Comment: The only thing that's missing from the above is line one:
Set tlRS=server.createobject("ADODB.Recordset")

And the .Open line.

Comment: Ok, I've slimmed it down quite a bit, here is an update:

    Set tlRS=server.createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
    tlText = "SELECT [Tracking # Label], Count([Tracking # Label]) AS LabelCount FROM CTM_Export"
    tlText = tlText & " WHERE [Tracking # Label] = 'TPE RV'"
    tlRS.Open tlText, "DSN=g_db"

This is MS Access DSN, by the way.

Comment: I'm also using the response.write shorthand to write it out like this: <%= LabelCount %>

This usually works but for some reason this doesn't.